# Microsoft Word page numbering keeps resetting to 0 after section break

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word document with two sections and page numbers throughout.  The second section is not linked to the previous, since I have other footer elements which would misalign if they were linked.  I have set the second section to continue page numbering from the previous section, but each time I save and reopen the document, the numbering in section 2 has reset to page 0.

Is this a bug or is there another setting I should know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly this problem today. Page number kept restarting to 0 in a new section. It didn't matter if next section was linked or not to the previous. No solution from forums worked (even macro for not restarting numbering at section from this [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-2013-page-numbering-reset-to-0-after-using-a/bedf7d48-ce8f-4f1a-80b7-023ab5a968b5?page=1)).

The solution that worked for me was **accepting tracked changes** just before, at and after the section **and then setting page numbers to continue from previous section one more time**. My section was probably inserted in track changes mode and Word couldn't handle it for some reason.

Comment: This also worked for me, but only if I stopped tracking changes before setting page numbers to continue from previous section for the final time.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I had this, specifically in the scenario mentioned in the thread you linked to, where next page section breaks are used mid-page, along with a 2 column layout with a bulleted list. Word just stopped respecting the "continue from previous section" page numbering option.
This macro from the page you linked to corrected the issue for me in that case:

`Sub SetContinuousPageNumbering()
Dim s As Section
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Sections
s.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers _
    .RestartNumberingAtSection = False
Next s
End Sub`